# How to get the key from a laravel form request?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have an array

```
array:2 [▼
  2 => "12"
  7 => "12"
]
```

Send from a form, I need the 2 and 7 how do i call them?

The keys are id's of parts so want to. 
foreach get the ID and value
then update something...

```
foreach($request->except('_token') as $part) {
    /*get Key here (in this case 2 or 7) and get value here (in this case both 12)*/
}
```

Can somebody tell me how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `$key => $value` notation in [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
foreach ($request->except('_token') as $key => $part) {
  // $key gives you the key. 2 and 7 in your case.
}
```

Comment: Weird looking code but works like charm, thank you!

Comment: @Armin You're welcome. Why do you think it's weird? `$request->except('_token')` gives you an array.  If that helps.

Answer (score 9):

```
$data = $request->except('_token')
foreach($data as $id => $value){
    echo "My id is ". $id . " And My value is ". $value;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `Collection` for a one-lined code instead of `foreach()`.

```
$requestKeys = collect($request->all())->keys();
```

Comment: `$requestKeys = collect($request->all())->keys()->all();` returns an array. 
The `all()` method returns the underlying array represented by the collection. 
Link: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-all

Answer (score 1):

If You want to access exactly one `$request` key, You can use:

```
$request->key_name
```

to achieve this.

#### Example

I was sending an `image` in postman like this:
[image: Postman image upload example]

And I got it in Laravel's controller like this:

```
public function store(SendMessageRequest $request)
{
    $image = $request->image; // this is what You need :)
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think answers here are incorrect.

They answer question, but question seem to be built on bad practice.

View should look something like this:

```
@foreach ($arrayItems as $arrayItem)
    <input type="text" name="arrayItems[{{ $arrayItem->id }}]">
@endforeach
```

Then your request would look like:

```
"arrayItems" => [
    2 => "12",
    7 => "12"
]
```

Now you can use `foreach ($request->arrayItems as $key => $arrayItem) {...}` or how ever it's required

Note: `arrayItems` is placeholder name for what ever variable name should be used in context like `users`, `posts` etc